# Stylus create mixins via loop

Tags: css, loops, mixins, stylus

My goal is create a group of mixins via array. 
My idea is apply code as follows:

```
f_colors = (f1 f2 f3 f4 f5)
for $i in 0..length(f_colors)
    v = f_colors[$i]
    num = $i+1

   f{num}cl()
      color v

   f{num}bg()
      background-color: v

// and use to generate css
body
   h1
       color: white
       f5bg ''
```

where in f_colors i've stored a colors list.
With thi example, i would obtain an output as

```
body h1 {
   background-color: #00f; // f5 color
   color: white;
}
```

is it possible, or my best could be use mixins as follows:

```
fbg(num)
    background-color: f_colors[num-1]

fcl(num)
    color: f_colors[num-1]
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to resort to using the `define` BIF:

```
$colors = (f1 f2 f3 f4 f5)
for $c, $i in $colors
  define("f"+($i + 1)+"bg", @() {
    background-color: $c
  })

// and use to generate css
body
  h1
    color: white
    f5bg ''
```

Comment: Did this answer ever work for you, Sim Sca? I'm trying something similar but running into issues, even though the code seems to compile fine. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61571888/stylus-creating-mixins-with-loop-results-in-override-issue